# Custom Hypercall in XEN

Tags: virtualization, xen, hypervisor

I was playing around with XEN kernel and I wanted to implement a custom hypercall on XEN. I added an entry in entry.S, defined a constant in `xen.h`, declared a prototype in `hypercall.h`  and made a new body too in `kernel.c` as written in this  [blog](http://sanifool.com/2013/02/08/invoking-an-hypercall-from-userland-via-privcmd).

I am getting an error saying that function is not implemented when i try to execute the hypercall. Iam using **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS** and **Xen 4.7**. Any idea why is the function not being implemented though I have clearly tried doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I've made an example for the Xen 4.13 version in this question: [how to add a hypercall in xen 4.13.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60564160/how-to-add-a-hypercall-in-xen-4-13-0)

Despite this question is previous to that one the idea is the same and I'm answering here to help someone that might get here before!

Answer (score -1):

Did you try in Privcmd (as of mentioned in that blog)?
I recently try it in Xen 4.6.1 and became runable with no problem. it may be because of wrong invoking method or less of privileged. have you ever solved it?
Regards.

Comment: if you not sure better put it as a comment

Comment: when i tried comment, it did not allow me to put comment. i don't know why. it tells me that you need 50 rep. after all i read such a posts before which others guess something because there is not enough presented evidences form questioner. regards.

Comment: Yea, the steps mentioned in the blog works perfectly. Problem's solved ! Thank you.

Comment: would you please tell us that how your problem became solved? Thanks.