# how to add a hypercall in xen 4.13.0

Tags: xen

I tried to follow tutorials to add a new hypercall for xen, however all of them cannot work because there is no ENTRY(hypercall_table) in entry.S, how to add a new hypercall in recent version of xen?

Comment: Please visit and check [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to create a custom hypercall is to watch how a simple one is declared and try to mimic the behavior.  I did this and was able to successfully write one.

The following steps were reproduced in **Xen 4.13**

Let's assume that I want to create an `attack` hypercall that will mimic some malicious behaviors inside Xen.

### 1 - Define the HC entry

`xen/include/public/xen.h`

```c
#define __HYPERVISOR_arch_6               54
#define __HYPERVISOR_arch_7               55 
/* Attack Emulation hypercall */
#define __HYPERVISOR_attack               56
```

### 2- Define its signature

`/xen/include/xen/hypercall.h`

```c
extern long
do_attack(
    int cmd,
    XEN_GUEST_HANDLE_PARAM(void) arg);
```

### 3- Declare its page in the assembly source

`/xen/arch/x86/guest/hypercall_page.S`

```
DECLARE_HYPERCALL(attack)
```

### 4- Declare it for the HVM mode

`/xen/arch/x86/hvm/hypercall.c`

```c
    HYPERCALL(arch_1),
    HYPERCALL(attack)
 };
```

### 5- Declare the number of parameters that it would have

`xen/arch/x86/hypercall.c`

```c
     ARGS(arch_1, 1),
     ARGS(attack, 2),
 };
```

### 6- Declare its body:

`/xen/common/kernel.c`

```c
DO(attack)(int cmd, XEN_GUEST_HANDLE_PARAM(void) arg)`
{
    printk("Entering Attack Hypercall:\t%d\n", cmd);
    return 0;
}
```